# How can I show a message box with contents of UITableViewCell when user long presses on it?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a table, and the data in some of the cells is too long and over runs. Although they can tap on it to go to the more details view the name, I want to add a way for them to long press on it for a few seconds and have the standard message box open with the full contents of the cell, then they can tap OK to dismiss it.

I know about `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` but I'm not sure where to go from there, with setting that up and then getting it to display cell's contents.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I'm using this code in a UITableViewController

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

//Recognize long tap
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
gestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.0; //seconds
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
[gestureRecognizer release];

}


 -(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];

if (indexPath != nil) {
//Do something
}
}
```